# Current limiter IC for motor driver

Tags: dc-motor, motor-controller, current-limiting, brushed-dc-motor

I'm using a full bridge [motor driver](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/dm00406533-1799025.pdf) to control a brushed DC motor.
The motor driver can provide up to 20A at 24VDC and I'm using 24VDC, 200Ah AGM batteries.

The driver offers the possibility to monitor the current output and this is very interesting for me because I can limit the maximum current by software.

I tried to search for current limiter circuits and some of them are based on the use of a transistor that is able to reduce the current when it turns ON.

Since the maximum current is very high for my application and so its power (20A*24VDC=480W), would it be better to use a current limiter IC? I wasn't able to find any commercial IC able to handle high currents.
Or should I use the transistor to limit the current?

My need is to be able to set a maximum current value for different working conditions.

Comment: I suggest that you study how this current limiting is done in real designs. Hint: there is no "current limiting circuit" as that would mean there's a series transistor that would need to dissipate enormous amounts of power. That's **very** impractical and you **will** destroy transistors. What is done is limiting the current by means of PWM, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation  also read about VFD: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-frequency_drive  To control a high power motor you **MUST** understand how current designs work so get studying.

Comment: I'm not an expert and I am not an electric engineer, so I'm asking this because I didn't study anything about this topic. However, I use Arduino to drive the motor driver, so do I just have to use a lower PWM to decrease the current by mapping the duty cycle with the current drawn by the motor? i.e. PWM at 80% -> current drawn 15A, PWM at 50% -> current drawn 10A?